# Simple array understanding

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a simple array in c++ which show me a strange result for default values of array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr [] = {2,3};

int main ()
{
  for ( int n=0 ; n<10 ; ++n ) {
    cout<< arr[n]<<",";

  }
}
```

The result of which I should receive is 2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, but get this result 2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,809998728,32588, can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Undefined behavior. You have are accessing outside the bounds of the 2 element array.

Comment: What makes you think you should get the 1st result actually? You are reading out of bounds from the array and that' s undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the array the following way

```
int arr [10] = {2,3};
```

Otherwise when it is declared like this

```
int arr [] = {2,3};
```

it has only two elements.

In any case the program would look better if it was written like

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int arr[N] = { 2, 3 };

    for ( size_t n = 0 ; n < N ; ++n ) std::cout << arr[n] << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Works but is not a big deal, can do simple int arr [10] = {3,4};

Comment: @Oana Andone It is a bad idea to use magic numbers in loops. So it is better to declare a named constant. If you will decide to change the size of the loop the loop will work without problems.

Comment: You can and should use `begin` and `end` to find the array dimensions in the loop. It's also a bad idea to loop up to `N` , the code could be broken more easily.

Comment: @Oana In my preceding comment I meant "If you will decide to change the size of the array...":)